# Changing instance attribute from another class method

Tags: python, oop

Is it possible to do this without using global variable? Is this considered a good coding practice or should I avoid it?

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array
    
    def method_a(self, scale):
        self.array = list(map(lambda x: x * scale, self.array))
        
class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def method_b(self):
        '''it throws an error when im not using global variable defined in main:'''
        if len(instance_a.array) > 5:
            instance_a.method_a(10)
        
def main():
    global instance_a
    array_ = [1,2,3,3,6,5]
    instance_a = ClassA(array_)
    instance_b = ClassB()
    instance_b.method_b()
```

**EDIT:** just assigned array_

Comment: Your code is not runnable. What is `array_` ?

Comment: `ClassB` should not be aware that someone created an instance of `ClassA`. You need to change your design.

Comment: You should avoid it! it is very bad, think if you use Class_B in severla places and suddendly someone chnages the name of instance_a nothing is going to work anymore, if you want to use Class_A inside Class_B pass instance_a as a paramaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring `instance_a` as a global, you can pass the local instance as a parameter to `method_b`.  Generally speaking, globals are to be avoided since the narrower the scope of a variable the easier it is debug should the need arise.

Example:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array
    
    def method_a(self, scale):
        self.array *= scale
        
class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def method_b(self, instance_a):
        if len(instance_a.array) > 5:
            instance_a.method_a(10)
        
def main():
    instance_a = ClassA(array_)
    instance_b = ClassB()
    instance_b.method_b(instance_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never need to do that. Also, I cant see where array_ is defined, which should raise an UnboundLocalError. Anyway, you will never production code expressed like that.